# ScrollBar Max Size VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, maxlength

How do you set the maximum range for the horizontal and vertical scrollbar in a panel
in VB.NET 2008 ?

Comment: Please explain the meaning of "maximum range"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The length you can scroll down or to the right.

Comment: And, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am making a program, for schools, that can generate tests. Each exercise wel be but in a panel en finaly that panel wil be put in a main panel where al of the exercise are held. Now when a student finisht a test i take a screenshot of the made test (so a teacher can recal the made test). So when the teacher  is making the test he can only place the exercises in a specific range ore outherwyse it wont fit on the sheet that the student is going to get.

Comment: Do not mind too bright for spelling errors. my english is not so fantastic.

Comment: You can't set a maximum size for the `AutoScroll` property. The scrollbar width/height is automatically resized to fit all of the content displayed in the scrollable control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AutoScroll property for the Panel to True.  That ensures that the Panel automatically adjusts the scrollbars to keep all controls inside the panel viewable.  You can override this behavior, in case you don't use controls or want a margin on the far end, by setting the AutoScrollMinSize property.